# Data not deleted from database

Tags: mysqli

I have a main table called "callshopusers"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `callshopusers` (
  `id_callshopuser` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_callshop` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_client` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_callshopuser`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

[image: Database structure]

But when I try to delete data from this table, it doesn't work. Here `id_client` column is used in another table as a Primary key.
My query for delete is:

```
$sql="DELETE FROM callshopusers WHERE id_callshopusers=$id";
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in id_callshopusers, should be id_callshopuser without 's'
$sql="DELETE FROM callshopusers WHERE id_callshopusers=$id";